# Prevent python script executing in pipeline if first one fails

Tags: python, shell

Is there a way to prevent script executing in pipeline if first one fails? If this was `bash` script we can set up `set -eo pipefail` and script will not be excute, but how it can be done in python?

will_fail.py

```
def fail():
    raise Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fail()
```

print_something.py

```
def print_something():
    print('something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_something()
```

Execution:
`python will_fail.py | python print_something.py`

Excepted output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "will_fail.py", line 5, in <module>
    fail()
  File "will_fail.py", line 2, in fail
    raise Exception
Exception
```

Actual output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "will_fail.py", line 5, in <module>
**Something**
    fail()
  File "will_fail.py", line 2, in fail
    raise Exception
Exception
```

By the way `Something` string appears at random line of output, makes me confused.

Comment: `Execution: python will_fail.py | python print_something.py` - this is still bash `script will not be excute` - no, this is not what happens. The script executes. `pipefail` only transfers the return status of the whole pipe, it doesn't mean it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a single file which imports both of the other files. Make each of the other files return either a true or false statement to show whether the code executed without any errors. In the main file, you can just do this:

```
if output1 == true:
   runScript2()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a specific reason to use a bash script, but in this case what I'd do is to make one script and call the two functions in a try/except block:

```
from will_fail import fail
from print_something import print_something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        fail()
        print_something()
    except:
        # do whatever is needed in case one of the scripts fail
```

This should work the way you described, so `print_something` will not be executed in case `fail` fails.